Chainlink function fulfilment counter malfunction
Wrote this code as a sample chainlink function consumer to test my end points, everything works and I get desired response and no errors but for some reason, the chainlink function fulfilment counter in the dashboard does not update rather it remains at 0. I also had to had code the name 'philip' as the value for the character as the information returned from my endpoint may not fit into that variable however this was for a test purpose, the main code will not have that.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.19;

import {FunctionsClient} from "@chainlink/contracts@1.1.1/src/v0.8/functions/v1_0_0/FunctionsClient.sol";
import {ConfirmedOwner} from "@chainlink/contracts@1.1.1/src/v0.8/shared/access/ConfirmedOwner.sol";
import {FunctionsRequest} from "@chainlink/contracts@1.1.1/src/v0.8/functions/v1_0_0/libraries/FunctionsRequest.sol";

/**
 * Request testnet LINK and ETH here: https://faucets.chain.link/
 * Find information on LINK Token Contracts and get the latest ETH and LINK faucets here: https://docs.chain.link/resources/link-token-contracts/
 */

/**
 * @title GettingStartedFunctionsConsumer
 * @notice This is an example contract to show how to make HTTP requests using Chainlink
 * @dev This contract uses hardcoded values and should not be used in production.
 */
contract GettingStartedFunctionsConsumer is FunctionsClient, ConfirmedOwner {
    using FunctionsRequest for FunctionsRequest.Request;

    // State variables to store the last request ID, response, and error
    bytes32 public s_lastRequestId;
    bytes public s_lastResponse;
    bytes public s_lastError;

    // Custom error type
    error UnexpectedRequestID(bytes32 requestId);

    // Event to log responses
    event Response(
        bytes32 indexed requestId,
        string character,
        bytes response,
        bytes err
    );

    // Router address - Hardcoded for Sepolia
    // Check to get the router address for your supported network https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-functions/supported-networks
    address router = 0xf9B8fc078197181C841c296C876945aaa425B278;

    // JavaScript source code
    // Fetch character name from the Star Wars API.
    // Documentation: https://swapi.info/people
     string poiProofSource =
        "const sender = args[0];"
        "const receiver = args[1];"
        "const apiResponse = await Functions.makeHttpRequest({"
        "url:`https://www.profiles.blue/api/getProofOfInteractionData?SenderAddress=${sender}&ReceiverAddress=${receiver}`"
        "});"
        "if(apiResponse.error){"
        "console.error(apiResponse.error);"
        "throw new Error(apiResponse.error);"
        "}"
        "const { data } = apiResponse;"
        "const sender_id = data.sender_id;"
        "const receiver_id = data.receiver_id;"
        "const timestamp = data.timestamp;"
        "const unixTimestamp = Math.floor(new Date(timestamp) / 1000);"
        "const resultString = JSON.stringify({ sender_id, receiver_id, timestamp: unixTimestamp ,sender, receiver});"
        "const encodedResult = Functions.encodeString(resultString);"
        "return encodedResult;";


    string exchangeProofSource = 
        "const sender = args[0];"
        "const receiver = args[1];"
        "const apiResponse = await Functions.makeHttpRequest({"
        "url:`https://www.profiles.blue/api/getInteractionBstData?SenderAddress=${sender}&ReceiverAddress=${receiver}`"
        "});"
        "if(apiResponse.error){"
        "console.error(apiResponse.error);"
        "throw new Error(apiResponse.error);"
        "}"
        "const { data } = apiResponse;"
        "const sender_id = data.sender_id;"
        "const receiver_id = data.receiver_id;"
        "const timestamp = data.timestamp;"
        "const unixTimestamp = Math.floor(new Date(timestamp) / 1000);"
        "const resultString = JSON.stringify({ sender_id, receiver_id, timestamp: unixTimestamp ,sender, receiver});"
        "const encodedResult = Functions.encodeString(resultString);"
        "return encodedResult;";
     

    //Callback gas limit
    uint32 gasLimit = 300000;

    // donID - Hardcoded for Sepolia
    // Check to get the donID for your supported network https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-functions/supported-networks
    bytes32 donID =
        0x66756e2d626173652d7365706f6c69612d310000000000000000000000000000;

    // State variable to store the returned character information
    string public character;

    /**
     * @notice Initializes the contract with the Chainlink router address and sets the contract owner
     */
    constructor() FunctionsClient(router) ConfirmedOwner(msg.sender) {}

    /**
     * @notice Sends an HTTP request for character information
     * @param subscriptionId The ID for the Chainlink subscription
     * @param args The arguments to pass to the HTTP request
     * @return requestId The ID of the request
     */
    function sendRequest(
        uint64 subscriptionId,
        string[] calldata args
    ) external onlyOwner returns (bytes32 requestId) {
        FunctionsRequest.Request memory req;
        req.initializeRequestForInlineJavaScript(exchangeProofSource); // Initialize the request with JS code
        if (args.length > 0) req.setArgs(args); // Set the arguments for the request
//77,["3J98t1WpEZ73CNmQviecrnyiWrnqDhUEWl","3J98t1WpEZ73CNmQviecrnyiWrnqDhTEWh"];
        // Send the request and store the request ID
        s_lastRequestId = _sendRequest(
            req.encodeCBOR(),
            subscriptionId,
            gasLimit,
            donID
        );

        return s_lastRequestId;
    }

    /**
     * @notice Callback function for fulfilling a request
     * @param requestId The ID of the request to fulfill
     * @param response The HTTP response data
     * @param err Any errors from the Functions request
     */
    function fulfillRequest(
        bytes32 requestId,
        bytes memory response,
        bytes memory err
    ) internal override {
        if (s_lastRequestId != requestId) {
            revert UnexpectedRequestID(requestId); // Check if request IDs match
        }
        // Update the contract's state variables with the response and any errors
        s_lastResponse = response;
        //hard coded for test purpose
        character = "philip";
        s_lastError = err;

        // Emit an event to log the response
        emit Response(requestId, character, s_lastResponse, s_lastError);
    }
}

I expected the counter to increase upon successful fulfilment, also I tried the code from chainlink docs with the endpoint on it , I got the desired result but still the counter remained 0.

Hey william, can you please paste the url to the dashboard with your subscription id so I can take a look? Thank you in advance!

I can't find any counter variable in the code that you've shared. Can you please highlight that?

@Andrej here is the url https://functions.chain.link/base-sepolia/77 and subscription ID id 77

@SYEDASADKAZMI, it is not a variable in the code but the fulfilment count in chainlink dashboard

Oh okay. In the url that you’ve shared, I can see the Fulfillments (i.e., fulfillment count) as 30 though?
